# Yellow Leaves & Brown Spots on Philodendron

Tags: diagnosis

My philodendron has been having tiny brown spots, yellow leaves, and some brown sticky substance that is similar to Coke or Pepsi. Some of the new leaves are partially brown and dried/dead when it blooms.

I’ve had it for years but it hasn’t grown much beyond its current size because the leaves end up brown and splitting (happened a few years ago) or the current situation I’ve encountered.  Does anyone have a clue?  The brown spots are creeping me out!

[image]